# stop table cell auto grow and follow height of cell in same row

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a table something like this

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="1" rowspan="2">
                Should control height of the long column
            </td>
            <td class="2">
                small content here
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="3" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                Lots of vertical content here that flows down and off the screen
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to set the height of class 3 to be class 1 - class 2.

Is this possible in CSS only? or is this a jquery call?

class 1 can continue to grow then on the active page and I would want class 3 to grow with that.

the issue is class 3 can contains large amounts of content and will just render the height of it all.

please note there are properties set that class 1 is 70% width of the page and class 2 and 3 are 20% width.

Comment: if you post html/ css/ js use fiddle

Comment: By the way, CSS class names must begin with a underscore (`_`), a hyphen (`-`), or a letter (`a-z`)

Comment: Hi Lars,

Sorry the class of 1 2 and 3 is just to describe which one I want to do what in this example.  They aren't actual classes in the code